# In Android Studio Java, I can't get values from STEP_COUNTER

Tags: java, android

When i run the code it doesn't print the values from STEP_COUNSTER Sensor.

Android SDK: 34

Gradle version: 8.2

Manifest:

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        if (sensorManager != null){
            Sensor stepCSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
            if (stepCSensor != null){
                sensorManager.registerListener(this, stepCSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Step count sensor not detected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sensors are not detected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

 @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER){
            vStepC.setText("Values: " + event.values[0]);
        } else {
            vStepC.setText("Not Found!");
        }
    }
```

It prints Not Found! in textview instead.

Comment: What is the value of the event?

Comment: value is steps taken by user, [Android reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)

Comment: Your if condition only handles one case and for all others it prints the log you mentioned. I would advise you to debug your logic to see what events you are getting.

Comment: event.sensor.getType() should return an int number which is 19 for STEP_COUNTER then the condition will be true and then .values[0] prints the steps but condition becomes false. because when i log the event it return nothing except my other sensor like accelerometer (int value 1).

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct, and it should display the step count values when the onSensorChanged method is triggered by the STEP COUNTER sensor. However, there might be some additional considerations to ensure everything works as expected:

TextView Initialization: Ensure that vStepC is properly initialized and refers to the TextView where you want to display the step count values.

UI Thread: Make sure that vStepC.setText() is called on the UI thread. If onSensorChanged() is called on a background thread (which might be the case depending on how the sensor manager is implemented), you should use runOnUiThread() or a similar mechanism to update UI components.

Check for Null Values: Always check for null values before accessing elements from the event.values array to avoid potential NullPointerExceptions.

Here's an updated version of your onSensorChanged() method with null checks and UI thread considerations:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER && event.values != null && event.values.length > 0){
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            vStepC.setText("Values: " + event.values[0]);
        });
    } else {
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            vStepC.setText("Not Found!");
        });
    }
}
```

By ensuring proper UI thread handling and null value checks, you can make sure that your TextView updates correctly based on the sensor data. If you're still experiencing issues, consider logging debug messages to understand the flow of your code and identify any potential problems.